# AWS IoT Core Protocol (mqtt), It's possible to apply JITP Just in time provisioning or JITR in one device embedded like Quectel BG95?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot

Hello I have an embedded system based on **BG95** quectel and I would like to know if it's possible to apply **JITP** or  **JITR with AWS IoT Core** with **MQTT** protocol for Fleet Provisioning process.?